# Django queryset keyword from string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my model

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  author = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

I have a json like this stored in db `q = {"field_name": "title", "value":"django"}` and this is what I am trying to do.

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(q["field_name"]=q["value"])
```

It is not working. Getting the error

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

How can i make this working ? I have tried things like

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(getattr(event_model, q["field_name"])=q["value"])
```

It is possible to make it work like many if elif conditions like below but the code becomes ugly. Is there any cleaner way to do this ?

```
if q["field_name"] == "title":
  Mymodel.objects.filter(title=q["value"])
elif q["field_name"] == "author":
  Mymodel.objects.filter(author=q["value"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *dictionary unpacking* technique as,

```
q = {"field_name": "title", "value": "django"}

Mymodel.objects.filter(**{q["field_name"]: q["value"]})
```

Comment: thanks. actually my json is a little more complicated. what i am trying to do is that storing the query as a json and later use it for querying the db. [{"field_name": "title", "value": "django", "condition": "equals"}, {"field_name": "author", "value": "dj", "condition": "contains"}]  any way i can fit in the condition somewhere ?